# How can this actionPerformed interact with my button?

Tags: java, swing, button

I am trying to allow the user to select what shape they want to draw on my GUI. I have a selection of buttons: circle, square and rectangle. My actionListener works as it prints a string to my console, but it won't show the shape on my GUI. How can I use the `actionCommand` to draw that shape on my panel.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, x2-x, y2-y);
    //g2D.draw(rect);
      repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
    if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Rect")){     
        System.out.println("hello");
        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, x2-x, y2-y);
        g2D.draw(rect); //can only be accessed within paintComponent method
        repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you firstly paint your rectangle and then ask for a repaint the rectangle will disappear.

You should store your new shape in a temp variable and render it inside paintComponent.

```
private Rectangle2D temp;

// inside the actionPerformed
    temp = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, x2-x, y2-y);
    repaint();

// inside the paintComponent
    if(temp != null) {
        g2D.draw(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the rect to be field nto local variable. In the actionPerformed create proper rect and call repaint(). Then paintComponent() will be called. It should be like this

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2D.draw(rect);
}
```

Comment: Also consider `super.paintComponent(g)`.